# RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [205] at entry 0 and [229] at entry 1

Tags: tensorflow

I am a secondary level practitioner, and in my practice they sent me to program a neural network that classifies complaints, I need someone's help because it gives me the following error:

It is based on a youtube tutorial, only adapted to work with BETO and does not classify between positive and negative but between two things: APIA -Insurance Claim and Securities Claim

RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [205] at entry 0 and [229] at entry 1

My code:

```
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
  print('Epoch {} de {}'.format(epoch+1, EPOCHS))
  print('------------------')
  train_acc, train_loss = train_model(
      model, train_data_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, device, scheduler, len(df_train)
  )
  test_acc, test_loss = eval_model(
      model, test_data_loader, loss_fn, device, len(df_test)
  )
  print('Entrenamiento: Loss: {}, accuracy: {}'.format(train_loss, train_acc))
  print('Validación: Loss: {}, accuracy: {}'.format(test_loss, test_acc))
  print('')
```

Comment: which line generating an error ?

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-8022754b3246> in <module>()
      5   print('------------------')
      6   train_acc, train_loss = train_model(
----> 7       model, train_data_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, device, scheduler, len(df_train)
      8   )
      9   test_acc, test_loss = eval_model(

Comment: <ipython-input-17-fdbe09a58dc9> in train_model(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, device, scheduler, n_examples)
      5   correct_predictions = 0
      6   for batch in data_loader:
----> 7     input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
      8     attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
      9     labels = batch['label'].to(device)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 0):

@Andrey

```
# Iteración entrenamiento
    def train_model(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, device, scheduler, n_examples):
      model = model.train()
      losses = []
      correct_predictions = 0
      for batch in data_loader:
        input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
        attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
        labels = batch['label'].to(device)
        outputs = model(input_ids = input_ids, attention_mask = attention_mask)
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
        correct_predictions += torch.sum(preds == labels)
        losses.append(loss.item())
        loss.backward()
        nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
      return correct_predictions.double()/n_examples, np.mean(losses)
    
    def eval_model(model, data_loader, loss_fn, device, n_examples):
      model = model.eval()
      losses = []
      correct_predictions = 0
      with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in data_loader:
          input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
          attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
          labels = batch['label'].to(device)
          outputs = model(input_ids = input_ids, attention_mask = attention_mask)
          _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
          loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
          correct_predictions += torch.sum(preds == labels)
          losses.append(loss.item())
      return correct_predictions.double()/n_examples, np.mean(losses)
```

Comment: please fix your question, your code is not properly formatted. Also add context to your question, which line is causing the error. What kind of data you are using and what is that you are trying to do also help people give you a meaningful answer.